# How to pack and unpack variadic template arguments into a structure?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, c++-templates

Suppose I have a variadic template which can take a number of parameters and it has to pack them in order to provide them to a C API. This is passed as a buffer or void* probably, but then fed back into the C++ layer as a callback and the C++ must be able to unpack this structure at runtime and interpret the result.
How can this be achieved?

I think the best example of what I am asking is how std::thread packs the parameter and provides them to CreateThread() and then how is the worker method able to somehow unpack the parameters?

```
std::thread temp([](int i, std::string s) { std::cout << i << s;}, 1, "asd");
```

How are the `i` and `s` parameters passed to CreateThread's function and how does this method know how to unpack?

EDIT: I am adding more detail to the question:

```
void CreateThread( void(void*) threadFunc, void* context);

void ProcessString(std::string s)
{
    std::cout << s;
}

void ProcessIntString(int i, std::string s)
{
    std::cout << i << " " << s;
}

std::thread sthread(ProcessString, "asd");
std::thread ithread(ProcessIntString, 3, "asd");
```

As you see, there is only one threadFunc but it knows how to unpack the `void* context` either to a string or an {int, std::string}.
So my questions are:

1. How does std::thread pack all parameters into that void*?
2. How does the threadFunc method know how to expand those parameters into a string, or possible an `int` + a `string`?
3. How are those parameter expanded fromone pointer into a variable number of arguments passed ie to `ProcessIntString`

Comment: not clear what you want, `f(args...)`, or `std::apply` with a tuple?

Comment: _"...How are the i and s parameters passed to CreateThread's function..."_ - see [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)

Comment: If you are curious about implementation details of `std::thread` on your particular implementation, you can look at the code or step through it in the debugger. Without looking, by guess would be that, at the bottom, the arguments are packed into a `std::tuple` and then the address of that tuple is passed to `CreateThread` via `LPVOID lpParameter` argument. If you are unsure how to apply this to your particular situation, explain that situation in more detail - show some code that illustrates what you wish to achieve.

Comment: you can always erase the type (like `std::bind` and `std::function`), pass the pointer to that object into thread and cast back then invoke.

Comment: "*This is passed as a buffer or void* probably*" What do you mean 'probably'? You need to know how the C API talks *before* you can do any packing or unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is just erase all the type.

for example, using `std::function<void()>`

```cpp
void CreateThread(void(*f)(void*), void* arg){
    f(arg);
}

// no forwarding for clarity
// parameters may be store inside the thread object
template <typename F,typename ...Args>
void InvokeInThread(F f,Args... args){
    std::function<void()> invoker = std::bind_front(f,args...);
    CreateThread(
        +[](void* f){
            reinterpret_cast<std::function<void()>*>(f)->operator()();
        },
        (void*)&invoker
    );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qhWa4TM5c